# Royal Mail Click and Drop will not Integrate through Firewall Reverse-Proxy

Tags: magento2, error, shipping, integration, proxy

Our Magento 2 (Magento Commerce Inc. Magento ver. 2.3.4-p2). Was previosuly integrated with Royal Mail Click and Drop and our orders on Magento migrated automatically to Click and Drop.

We have recently had to move over to Sucuri and as a result the Magento 2 instance will no longer integrate with Click and drop. I have included a screenshot below to show the problem.

[image]

We have whitelisted all the necessary i.p. addresses on both the firewall and the server but the problem persists. When we contacted our firewall provider they gave the following response.

> The Sucuri Firewall is a Web Application Firewall that serves the by
> what is considered a reverse-proxy.
>
> The flow of traffic now looks like this:
>
> User ===> Firewall ===> Hosting Server
>
> Given this new info from Royal Mail, I'd recommend to review the
> integration settings and ensure that Royal Mail is referencing your
> hosting server via IP address xx.xxx.xxx.xxx, as opposed to the
> Firewall IP address yyy.yyy.yyy.yy.

Having sent this to Royal Mail, they responded with the following:

> We wouldn't be able to connect directly to your IP, as we currently
> use URL's to integrate with, you will need to investigate and address
> this at you end to allow us to see the right IP.   Please accept my
> apologies that we are unable to assist further with this.

Has anyone else run across this issue and is there a solution that will allow us to use Click and Drop with the new firewall?

Update - 06 July 2020

Royal Mail and SUCURI have finally gotten back to us and suggested setting up a subdomain and having click and drop integrate through that.

We've set up a subdomain which redirects to the original i.p. but we aren't sure how to get the integrations to use the new domain.

If anyone has any ideas about this we'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Evidently there is no way to do this.

I have been back and forth between Sucuri and Royal Mail several times over a number of weeks and neither seems to be able to propose a viable resolution to this issue.

I will have to look for an alternative firewall solutions